# How to delete files and folders except few folders using java

Tags: java

I have the following folder structure  which contains some zip files, xml files and folders. I want to clear all the data except `Result folder and Report folder.`

```
File theDir = new File(filePath+"Process/");
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(theDir);
```

**Folder structure:**

Process

- xml files
- zip files
- Input folder
- Result folder
- Report folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileUtils.cleanDirectory` method does not allow selective clean. You need to write your own method, something like this:

```
void cleanDirectory(File dir) {
    for (File file: dir.listFiles()) {
        if(file.getName().equals("Result folder") || file.getName().equals("Report folder")) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            //delete file
            file.delete();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always list all files using a filenamefilter.
So, you can create a list of File objects (dir/files) to delete

```
String pendingDelete[] = new File("/path/to/dir").list(new FileNameFilter() {
             public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                 if (name.equals("Result folder") || name.equals("Report folder")){
                   return false;
                 } 
                 return true;
             }
         });
for (String s : pendingDelete) {
   new File(s).delete();
}
```